# Apache Camel MockEndpoint mock the output

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, apache-camel

Let's say I have an apache camel route like this:

```
from("direct:start")
    .routeId("aRouteId")
    .bean(someBusinnessTransformationBean).id("transformationBean")
    .bean(aPersistenceBean).id("persistenceBean")
    .to("direct:target");
```

And then, on my unit tests, I'm doing something like:

```
public class RouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    @Override
    public boolean isDumpRouteCoverage() { return true }

    @Override
    public boolean isUsedAdviceWith() { return true }

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:mockTransformationBean")
    protected MockEndpoint mockTransformationBean;

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:mockPersistenceBean")
    protected MockEndpoint mockPersistenceBean;

    @Test
    public void testRoute() throws Exception {
        context.getRouteDefinition("aRouteId").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                weaveById("transformationBean")
                    .replace()
                    .multicast()
                    .to(mockTransformationBean);

                weaveById("persistenceBean")
                    .replace()
                    .multicast()
                    .to(mockPersistenceBean);
            }
        });

        context.start();

        // Asserts the expectedMessageCount

        // Send a message with template.sendBody...

        assertMockEndpointSatisfied();
    }
}
```

**Question:**

How could I unit test this route properly, instead of just ensure the messageCount and received body (on the first bean).

Like, how could I mock the response of a MockEndpoint as I could do when using Mockito for unit testing:

```
when(mockTransformationBean.someHandler(...)).thenReturn(anExpectedObjectForMyUnitTestPropose);
```

Cheers, Nikolas

Comment: Why don't you just run the unit test and then compare the exchange body against some expected body?

Comment: Because I couldn't find a way to intercept the exchange body of the bean with the apache camel MockEndpoint. What I can is ensure the received body to the mock, but then, I want to ensure the first bean transform the body and send a different one to the second bean.

Comment: You can do an adviceWith and after the bean intercept and send it to a mockendpoint. Then assert what the message should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, documentation reading and so on, I come up with an acceptable solution for this:

```
weaveById("transformationBean")
    .replace()
    .to(mockTransformationBean)
    .setBody(constant(<myExpectedMockResponse>));
```

So later on, I can just do an assert like:

```
mockPersistenceBean.expectedBodiesReceivedInAnyOrder(
    <myExpectedMockResponse>
);
```

This way, it is possible to ensure not just if the beans and endpoints are receiving the proper body / header, but if any transformation in between the route is being done properly as well.

So it is possible to test the input and output of the code from a unit point of view, instead integrating it with a lot of other components unnecessary in an unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You could build exchanges individually and call the bean methods; that is, don't send them in via Camel - just call the beans directly. That's a more controlled and targeted unit test.

Comment: Ok, I got the point. The only bit I'm quite confuse is, how could I ensure that all the camel routes written are properly wrote? The beans themself already have unit tests. But how could I ensure the developers later on, who will do maintenance to the code, will not break the route, without breaking the beans?

Comment: Well why don't you create an exchange, and in your unit test send the exchange or the exchange body to the bean class and then do an expectation match. To test the entire route you need to run the route and mock away external dependencies.